# Agrupar duas colunas em duas tabelas mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Tenho duas tabelas que estou unindo para recuperar os dados relacionados dessa forma:

```
Tabela Processos:              Tabela Anexos

id  |  processos              processoid  |  titulo         

1   |  Processo 1             1           |  REQUERIMENTO 
2   |  Processo 2             1           |  Apostilamento
3   |  Processo 3             2           |  requisição
4   |  Processo 4             2           |  REQUERIMENTO  
5   |  Processo 5             3           |  Apostilamento
6   |  Processo 6             3           |  CRAF

SELECT processos.processos, 
       processos.id as processoid, 
       anexos.*, 
       anexos.id as anexoid 
  FROM anexos 
  INNER JOIN processos ON (processos.id = anexos.processoid) 
  GROUP By processos.id 
  ORDER By anexos.processoid
```

Com a query acima ele retorna da seguinte forma:

```
Processo 1 =>  REQUERIMENTO 
Processo 1 =>  Apostilamento

Processo 2 =>  requisição
Processo 2 =>  REQUERIMENTO

Processo 3 =>  Apostilamento
Processo 3 =>  CRAF
```

O que preciso está abaixo:

```
Processo 1 =>  REQUERIMENTO 
               Apostilamento

Processo 2 =>  requisição
               REQUERIMENTO

Processo 3 =>  Apostilamento
               CRAF
```

Creio que é só o uso do GROUP BY mas nesse caso nao funciona.

Comment: Por que o primeiro resultado não te atende?

Comment: Olá, não me atende porque quero exibir o valor do processo agrupado e não repetido.

Comment: Não é simples fazer isso, você teria que montar uma view ou uma procedure para fazer isso, e são bem complexas de programar. Uma solução rápida para o problema seria você programar o seu php para apresentar da forma que você quer.

Comment: então amigo, eu sei que tem como fazer manipulando a consulta, nesse caso acho que tem a ver com o GROUP By pois eu preciso retornar o campo processo 1 vez para cada titulo da tabela Anexos, nesse aí ele repete o campo processo.

Comment: Group By não resolve plano cartesiano, no seu caso está retornando o índice duas vezes porque os resultados da segunda coluna é diferente.

Comment: será que fazendo duas query separadas resolveria?

Comment: Sempre vai trazer dois resultados?

Comment: não, é aleatório, algumas 3 outras 5...

Comment: Aí complica. Insisto que dá pra fazer com php. Você quer apresentar isso em uma tabela certo?

Comment: eu vou listar os documentos de cada processo em relação ao titulo, talvez use tabela mas acho que vou fazer algo mais intuitivo.

Comment: Você traz o resultado do banco em array ou objeto ?

Comment: Eu trago em array, faço um foreach e exibo os processos e os titulos.

Comment: Esse retorno está em que linguagem?

Comment: retorno é PHP direto.

Comment: Então os nomes dos processos seriam as chaves, correto?

Comment: Da forma como você quer, só mesmo para fazer na linguagem, no caso o php

Comment: Exato, e eu faria ele montar tela através de condições enquanto ele percorre o loop.

Comment: Isto deve ser feito em sua aplicação e não na consulta SQL já que esta "repetição" é o que se espera do resultado da query. O uso de algum report generator facilita bastante fazer o que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, não foi bem uma solução genérica que encontrei, mas sim uma lógica diferente e o entendimento de que a logica não precisaria de exibir os nomes dos processos mas somente os titulos, nesse caso nao foi necessário nenhuma mudança, já que o objetivo é exibir os titulos de cada processo.

Entao a Query ficou assim mesmo e retornei da forma abaixo:

```
        $valida = $this->db->query("SELECT processos.processos, processos.id as processoid, anexos.*, anexos.id as anexoid FROM anexos INNER JOIN processos ON (processos.id = anexos.processoid) WHERE processos.id = '$this->processo'");




foreach ($valida->fetchAll() as $folderProcesso) {
        echo $folderProcesso['titulo'] .' Data: '.folderProcesso['data'];
}
```

Ressalvo que nao foi necessario o uso do GROUP BY já que os titulo são diferentes e nao duplicam.